# PySpark - DataFrame's columns that include nested dictionaries are modified when converted to StringType

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, type-conversion, databricks

**Environment:** Databricks, PySpark 3.3.2

**Context:** I'm trying to build a PySpark DataFrame from the data obtained through a REST API get request. The data that I get from the API is in JSON format and contains nested dictionaries.
Example:

```
{'id': '5301620',
 'key': 'PROJECT-151',
 'changelog': {'startAt': 0,
  'maxResults': 1,
  'total': 1,
  'histories': [{'id': '12164785',
    'author': {'accountId': '62fbf0268bddf1c9',
     'displayName': 'name',
     'active': True,
     'timeZone': 'Europe'},
    'created': '2023-05-26T08:54:01.580+0200',
    .
    .
    .
}
```

To create a DataFrame from the API requests I'm using a udf with the following return type schema :

```
udf_schema = T.ArrayType(
    T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("self", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("expand", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("key", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("id", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("changelog", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())),
            T.StructField("fields", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()))
        ]
    )
)


@F.udf(returnType=udf_schema)
def execute_request(project_key, start_at):
    API_client = connect_to_API()   # Connect to the API
    _result = API_client.request(project_key, start_at)  # Request the data and store it as a list of dictionaries
    API_client.close()              # Close the connection to the API
    return _result

# list_of_rest_api_requests is a list of Row that contains
# the information needed (project_key and start_at) to make the API requests.
df = spark.createDataFrame(list_of_rest_api_requests)
df = df.withColumn("data", execute_request(F.col("project_key"), F.col("start_at")))
```

**Issue:** When casting my nested dictionaries to StringType using the MapType(StringType, StringType) data type of PySpark the nested dictionaries are modified. The ":" become "=" and the quotes are deleted.
If we take the previous example, the data in my DataFrame inside the column 'changelog' will look like this:

```
object
total: "1"
histories: "[{id=12164785, created=2023-05-26T08:54:01.580+0200, author={accountId=62fbf0268bddf1c9, displayName=name, timeZone=Europe, active=true}}]"
maxResults: "1"
startAt: "0"
```

Is it a bug or a normal behavior ?
Is there a way to fix it so that it looks like this :

```
object
total: "1"
histories: "[{'id':'12164785', 'created':'2023-05-26T08:54:01.580+0200', 'author':{'accountId':'62fbf0268bddf1c9', 'displayName':'name', 'timeZone':'Europe', 'active':True}}]"
maxResults: "1"
startAt: "0"
```

This small modification is annoying for me because I would like to use from_json() on certain column later to convert them to StructType or ArrayType and access the nested columns easily.

**Small example that you can use to reproduce it:**

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T

project_data = [
    (1,{"issue_key":"abc", "col1":{'a':2342,'b':2}}),
    (2,{"issue_key":"abc", "col2":[{'a':2342,'b':2}, {'c':'grha','d':True}]}),
    (3,{"issue_key":"abc", "col1":{'a':5,'b':21}})
    ]
schema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("project_id", T.IntegerType()),
        T.StructField("columns", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType()))
    ]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(project_data, schema)
df.display()
```

This is the output I get :

[image: output]

**Additional information**

- The data I am processing may have different schema so I prefer not to hard code the schemas. The schema may also change over time and I would like to have my code handle the changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the output using below code. And here schema is not hardcoded, to get the inner level data, you need to explode the nested columns.

```
data = [("""{
"id": 12164785,
"created": "2023-05-26T08:54:01.580+0200",
"author": {
    "accountId": "62fbf0268bddf1c9",
    "displayName": "name",
    "timeZone": "Europe",
    "active": "True"
}
}""")]

 df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data))
 df.display()
```

you can see the output as below

[image]

Comment: The issue is that I'm creating my dataframe in a distributive way using a udf so I don't have any variable that holds the entire data inside a list of json. Is there a way to still use your method in that case ?

Comment: yes you can read from json file as well. Make sure the json is valid.                                                                       
     df = spark.read.json(json_file_path)

Comment: I am not reading from a json file. My API requests are directly stored inside the Pyspark DataFrame so I don't think that your answer is suitable in my case